# Most stable version of Spring 3.x?

Tags: spring, frameworks, version

I want to upgrade to a Spring 3.x version, and I would like to know which one is the most stable. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I like that "no bugs" part :D

Comment: @Random yeah, good luck finding any version of any library with "No Bugs"

Comment: Even in the latest, greatest, most stable version of Spring (3.0.5), there are 87 verified bugs. No such thing as "no bugs" in software this complicated.

Answer (score 7):

As of this moment:

> Spring Framework 3.2.9.RELEASE is the current production release

http://www.springsource.org/download

You can download from here

http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/springframework/spring/3.2.9.RELEASE/

Comment: It is actually latest in 3.x.x series!

Answer (score 0):

As of now the spring Latest GA release is: 3.2.0.RELEASE

[http://www.springsource.org/spring-community-download](http://www.springsource.org/download/community)